# Python cycling through pairs of items while at the same time removing already checked items

Tags: python, list

Problem: I have a list of unique items and a comparison_tool to compare a certain property of item-pairs.

I want to store all items that return 1 for the comparison_tool for any other item without unnecessary comparisons.

Is there an efficient way to cycle through the list?
I have tried figuring it out with itertools.combinations(list_of_items, 2) and also failed with the example below:

```
def comparison_tool(a, b):
    '''Checks if prop matches (this is simplified for this example 
       and i can't break it out of this function)
    '''
    if a.prop == b.prop:
         return 1 # this is bad
    else:
         return 0

list_of_items = [...]
faulty_items = set()    
for a in list_of_items:
     for b in list_of_items: 
         if comparison_tool(a,b):
             faulty_items.add(a,b)
             list_of_items.remove(b) 
             # Here is where i go wrong. I would like to remove 'b' from list_of_items
             # so that 'a' doesn't cycle through 'b' in its upcoming loops
```

Or am i just going about this the wrong way?

Comment: If you wanna use if comparison_tool(a,b), you should return True/False in your function.

Comment: What is it that you really want to do? Get a list of all items that have the same value for `.prop`?

Comment: Just a example : you have in you list `a` and `b` with `a.prop == b.prop`. Do you want to keep just `a`, just `b` or neither of two ?

Comment: I might have caused some confusion, the comparison_tool is a third party tool that is computationally expensive.
The a.prop == b.prop is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

You should use list comprehension and do:

```
newlist = [i for i in list_of_items if i.prop=1]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler to create a new list containing good values :

```
list_of_items = [...]
faulty_items = set()
new_list = []
for i in list_of_items:
    for j in new_list:
        if comparison_tool(i, j):
            faulty_items.add(i)
            break
    else:
        new_list.append(i)

list_of_items = new_list
```